# androidで絶対に死なないserviceを作成するには

Tags: android

androidで、Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTORを使用して歩数計アプリを作成しようとしています。
serviceでTYPE_STEP_DETECTORの結果を取得して、アプリ内のDBに日時と歩数を保持しようとしています。
よって、serviceは常に動作しておく必要があります。

絶対に死なないserviceを作成するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

現状は、onStartCommandの戻り値で、START_STICKY を返却しています。

・アプリを終了
・履歴から削除
・EclipseのDDMSのSTOPボタンで削除
上記の場合は、しばらくするとサービスが再起動しました。

・アプリのデータ削除
上記の場合は、サービスが再起動しませんでした。

絶対に死なないサービスを作成する方法はあるのでしょうか？
何卒アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

絶対に死なないわけではありませんが、
定期的に alarm を BroadcastReceiver で受け取って、そこから startService() するのはいかがでしょう? 死んでしまっても再起動することができます。

または、startForeground() するとかなり死ににくくはなります。

余計なお世話かもしれませんが、歩数計なら TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR より TYPE_STEP_COUNTER の方が適しているのでは? という気もしました。

Comment: サービスのonStartCommandでアラームを仕込んで、BroadcastReceiverで受け取って、startServiceするようにしようと思います。ありがとうございました。

TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR を使おうと思ったのは、歩いた時の日時を取得したかったかです。TYPE_STEP_DETECTORだとリスナーで歩数といっしょに日時がとれそうだったのでTYPE_STEP_DETECTORを使用しようと思いました。